# How to export tags from Stackoverflow to a excel file?

Tags: tags, extract, stack-overflow, export-to-csv, text-extraction

I am trying to pull the questions posted on Stackoverflow for a specific tag and export all the questions to an excel/csv file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run appropriate query on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) and click on "Download CSV" link.

Also you can download a [complete DB dump](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent) (the link is on the DB.stackexchange help page)

Comment: what is the column name for questions associated with the tags?

Comment: @wicked_sunny the DB scheme is on the right. `Posts` table contains `Tags` column.

Comment: Thank you!!But the query returns only 50000 rows which is not the entire database. How can I run the query for the entire database?

Comment: @wicked_sunny seems you have to download the DB dump (I updated my answer recently)

Comment: Thank you. Its 22 Gb. Going to take a while to download the entire thing.